# Building driver for Ralink RT5370 USB WiFi WLAN Dongle

Tags: drivers, usb, wireless

I have a [Trim-Slice Value](http://trimslice.com/web/trim-slice-value-specifications) using Ubuntu 11.04. It comes with a [Ralink RT5370 802.11n WiFi dongle](http://www.ralinktech.com/en/02_products/product.php?sn=1007).

When I plug the dongle in, it does not 'just work'; `ifconfig` and `iwconfig` do not show the device, though `lsusb` does show the device listed:

```
phrogz@trimslice:~$ lsusb | grep Ralink
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 148f:5370 Ralink Technology, Corp.
```

I downloaded the link for RT5370 from [Ralink's Linux Drivers site](http://www.ralinktech.com/en/04_support/support.php?sn=501), resulting in a file named `2011_0225_RT5370_RT5372_Linux_STA_V2.5.0.1_DPO.tar.bz2`. After extracting it, the only README in the file mentions the "RT2870 Wireless Lan Linux Driver"; however, the Makefile at the root of the directory does have these lines:

```
ifeq ($(CHIPSET),)
CHIPSET = 5370
endif
```

I edited `os/linux/config.mk` to have these settings:

```
# Support Wpa_Supplicant
HAS_WPA_SUPPLICANT=y

# Support Native WpaSupplicant for Network Maganger
HAS_NATIVE_WPA_SUPPLICANT_SUPPORT=y
```

When I return to the root of the extracted directory and run `make`, however, it fails:

```
phrogz@trimslice:~/2011_0225_RT5370_RT5372_Linux_STA_V2.5.0.1_DPO$ sudo make
[sudo] password for phrogz: 
make -C tools
make[1]: Entering directory `/home/phrogz/2011_0225_RT5370_RT5372_Linux_STA_V2.5.0.1_DPO/tools'
gcc -g bin2h.c -o bin2h
make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/phrogz/2011_0225_RT5370_RT5372_Linux_STA_V2.5.0.1_DPO/tools'
/home/phrogz/2011_0225_RT5370_RT5372_Linux_STA_V2.5.0.1_DPO/tools/bin2h
cp -f os/linux/Makefile.6 /home/phrogz/2011_0225_RT5370_RT5372_Linux_STA_V2.5.0.1_DPO/os/linux/Makefile
make -C /lib/modules/2.6.38.3-trimslice-1.03/build SUBDIRS=/home/phrogz/2011_0225_RT5370_RT5372_Linux_STA_V2.5.0.1_DPO/os/linux modules
make: *** /lib/modules/2.6.38.3-trimslice-1.03/build: No such file or directory.  Stop.
make: *** [LINUX] Error 2
```

**How can I build the driver for this device?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I use a Tenda W311M that uses the same chip.
Thanks for mentioning the download URL for the driver.

This thread http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1285828 mentions the solution.

I hope it works for you.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Answer (score 1):

You have to install Linux headers corresponding to you kernel release, to get the build directory mentioned:

```
apt-get install linux-headers-[version]
```

You can get the kernel release by typing:

```
uname -r
```