# ifconfig can't see USB wireless

Tags: wireless, networking, 14.04, usb

I have a wifi USB dongle which I have previously used on a Raspberry Pi (this it is what it is target at).

I am trying to get it working on an Nvidia Jetson TK1, however I am having some problems.

When I run `ifconfig` I can't see the wifi, only the ethernet and local loopback.

`iwconfig` reports no wireless extensions on all devices.

`lsusb` does find the device:

```
Bus 002 Device 008: ID 148f:5370 Ralink Technology, Corp. RT5370 Wireless Adapter
```

So I am not sure why the network tools can't see it.

I have tried logging on with a GUI and opening up the network settings through Unity, but cannot see any wireless devices either.

Not sure if this is useful, but output of `lsmod`:

```
Module                  Size  Used by
nvhost_vi               2940  0
```

How can I enable wireless networking on this computer?

Command line approach is preferred, but either is fine.

**UPDATE**

I don't have the kernel module rt2800usb anywhere on my system.  If I do an apt-file search for rt2800usb it lists a number of packages of the pattern: linux-image-3.13.0-*.

Perhaps installing one of these will do the trick, but can anyone tell me if its safe to do so?

Comment: Is that Raling or Ralink? Ralink drivers have to be compiled from source, iirc.

Comment: Ralink (corrected).  Are you sure?  I haven't had to do this in Raspbian.

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/questions/99373/building-driver-for-ralink-rt5370-usb-wifi-wlan-dongle I had to, every time I faced an Ralink device in the past year (usually laptop cards).

Answer (score 2):

That device is covered by *rt2800usb* in newer Ubuntu versions. Check:

```
modinfo rt2800usb | grep 5370
```

You should see this:

```
alias:          usb:vF201p5370d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v148Fp5370d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
```

If you do, load the module and see if the wireless comes to life:

```
sudo modprobe rt2800usb
```

Get the module to load automagically on boot:

```
sudo -i
echo rt2800usb  >>  /etc/modules
exit
```

If your Ubuntu version is older, I suggest you upgrade. It will probably be easier than compiling from Ralink's source code.

Comment: I get `ERROR: Module rt2800usb not found`.  Might be a problem! Is there a package I can install to get this?

Comment: What Ubuntu version are you running? uname -r and also: lsb_release -d Thanks.

Comment: uname -r gives: 3.10.24-g6a2d13a, and lsb_release gives: Ubuntu 14.04.1 LTS.  Cheers.

Comment: It is safe to install the later 3.13 kernel which will give you rt2800usb and drive your device. If there is an 'extras' package along with the linux-image, be sure to install it, too.

Answer (score 0):

Flashing the Jetson with *The Grinch* got my Ralink USB modem working. The instructions may be found here:
  [The Grinch 19.3.6 for Jetson TK1](https://devtalk.nvidia.com/default/topic/766303/embedded-systems/-customkernel-the-grinch-19-3-4-for-jetson-tk1/)

You will need at least 15 Gig available on the host computer for the procedure to work.

I chose this option because of the long list of kernel improvements listed.

Answer (score 0):

1. Check the kernel version of Jetson TK1 by using command `uname –r`
2. Go to the [website](https://www.kernel.org/pub/linux/kernel/projects/backports/stable/), based on kernel version of Jetson TK1, select the respective Linux kernel backports to download.
3. After completed download, extract the backports folder.
4. Type command `make`
5. Type command `sudo make install`
6. Type command `sudo reboot`
7. Plug in USB WiFi dongle and now you should see your USB WiFi dongle.